# How can I hide a centreButton in spaceNavigationView and keep its space?

Tags: android-studio

I'm new to android programming, and there isn't so much documentation about SpaceNavigationView.
I want to hide the centerButton and to keep the space given to it.

Here is the menu :
[image: menu before hiding the centre button]

I want to hide the button "sos"

Here is my code :

```
if (settingsProfils.sos == 1) {
    space.setSpaceBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.color.gris));
    space.setCentreButtonIcon(R.drawable.sos);
    space.setActiveCentreButtonIconColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    space.setInActiveCentreButtonIconColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    space.setCentreButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.color.coral_pink));
    space.setFont(type);
    space.hideCenterButton(1);

} else {
    space.setSpaceBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.color.gris));
    space.setCentreButtonIcon(R.drawable.sos);
    space.setActiveCentreButtonIconColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    space.setInActiveCentreButtonIconColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    space.setCentreButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.color.gris));
    space.hideCenterButton(0);

}
```

and this is the result : [image: after hiding the centre button]

The problem is that I want to keep the space given to the button so that the other items in the menu stay in their positions (I mean they can't move).

Comment: Maybe not the best option but, you can test to set a margin between these two buttons, I mean a right margin on one button and left margin in other one. Just as an idea..

Comment: Thank u, but it won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding :

```
CentreButton centreButton = space.getCentreButton();
centreButton.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
```

And modify the last line in else block by :

```
space.hideCenterButton(1);
```